# Q promise .then() undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, q

I am attempting to asynchronously pull data from a MySQL database then process the results with Q promise (first attempt ever).  I am using the Q defer() function listed [here](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#adapting-node).  I have created a "wrapper" object I will eventually attach to req.db or access via circular dependency from com.db (how it is currently used) to allow for an api use in my app.

Node throws an error pointing at the .then callback:

```
this.go().then(function(stuff){
                          ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined
```

I have tried the following:

```
var com = require('./mainRebuild');

function Base() {
    this.results = [];
    this.query = 'query here';
    this.go = function() {

        com.pool.getConnection(function(err, con) {

            if (err) throw err;
            /*
            THIS WORKS FINE (with callbacks)
             con.query('SELECT * FROM Users', function(err, rows){
                if (err) throw err;
                if (rows){

                  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
                    this.results.push(rows[i]);
                    //console.log(rows[i]);
                  }
                }
                con.release();
                return this.results;
              }.bind(this));

              */
            var defer = com.Q.defer();
            con.query('SELECT * FROM Users', defer.makeNodeResolver());
            return defer.promise();
        }.bind(this));
    }
}

function DB() {
    this.getAllUsers = function() {
        this.query = 'SELECT * FROM Users';
        this.go().then(function(stuff) {
            console.log(stuff);
        }, function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

}

DB.prototype = new Base();

module.exports = DB;
```

The com object exists in the main app, it holds all the common require modules.

I also tried (seems far more wrong):

```
this.deffered = com.Q.defer();
com.pool.getConnection(function(err, con) {

            if (err) this.deferred.reject(new Error(err));

            con.query('SELECT * FROM Users', function(err, rows) {
                if (err) throw err;
                if (rows) {
                    this.deferred.resolve(rows);
                }
                con.release();
                return this.deferred.promise.done;
            }.bind(this));

            com.Q.nfcall(this.go()).then...
```

I have found several articles on adapting Q to node like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505850/q-js-using-deferred).

Comment: `this.go` doesn't return anything...

Comment: I guess I'm just confused with the nested deferred function I'm trying to write.  Can you explain how to make this.go return the nested deferred?

Comment: Create the promise inside `go`, not inside the callback. Here is a simplified example: `function foo() { function bar() { return 42; }; bar(); }` . Do you expect `foo()` really to return `42`?

Comment: `return defer.promise();`
Should be

`return defer.promise;`

Comment: yup putting defer outside the callback then returning in foo worked perfect.  Also `defer.promise`.  Someone please write up the answer and I will accept it! Thanks guys!

Comment: For future viewers this example helped alot: https://gist.github.com/jeffcogswell/8257755

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do it ("should", because I have no way to test it with MySQL)

```
var Q = require('Q');

function DB(pool) {
    this.asyncQuery = function(sql) {
        return function () { 
            var result = Q.defer(),
                paramsArray = [].slice.call(arguments);
            pool.getConnection(function(err, con) {
                if (err) return result.thenReject(err);
                con.query(sql, paramsArray, result.makeNodeResolver());
                result.promise.finally(function () {
                    con.release();
                });
            });
            return result.promise;
        };
    };
    this.getAllUsers = this.asyncQuery('SELECT * FROM Users');
    this.getUserByName = this.asyncQuery('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE name = ?');
}

module.exports = DB;
```

Usage:

```
var DB = require('./DB');
var com = require('./mainRebuild');
var db = new DB(com.pool);

db.getAllUsers().then(function (users) {
    console.log(users);
});

db.getUserByName('JohnDoe').then(function (user) {
    console.log(user);
});

var customQuery = db.asyncQuery('SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id = ?');
customQuery(42).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: beautiful.  adding a factory function to module.exports returning new DB() allows the exported object to be fully chainable. :D  e.g. `module.exports = createApp;  function createApp() { return new DB(); }`

Comment: Also see modified answer. The definition of `DB` does not need to know that `pool` is defined in `'./mainRebuild'`. We can inject that.

Comment: Is there a reason to not import the dependency from `'./mainRebuild'` ?  Is injecting preferable, how it is superior ?

Comment: Well, it's none of your DB adapter's concern which connection to use. You could (in theory) have several databases or connection pools, passing the pool to the DB constructor allows that pattern.

Comment: Sorry to dig up that thread, but I like the way you modularized that code, but with that way, the connection isn't released. Isn't it risky?

Comment: @krakig You are correct, I did not think about that when I wrote this answer. I've added a `finally` callback that closes the connection.